# Not be able to connect to Azure SQL after connect through VPN

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, vpn

I am having a really wired problem with my home laptop.

Below is what I have done:

I have set up my own VPN via AWS.
I added VPN ip address to Azure SQL firewall ip table

By not having VPN, I can connect to Azure easily.
However, once I connect to the VPN, I got error when I try to connect to Azure.

Error message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer
>   available.)

On the other hand, I can use VPN and connect to Azure SUCCESSFULLY from my office desktop.

I believe this is something to do with my Home laptop settings. 
but even I disabled firewall on windows 7,
and after disable firewall on azure SQL as well.

I still having same connection problem

any ideas?

Comment: What does your `ip route` or `route -n` output look like?

Comment: have you tried specifying the fully qualified domain name (fqdn ) when connecting ?

Comment: @GX. may i ask a newbie question: if it is my home laptop (private use) can I still do  fully qualified domain name (fqdn )?? any link that i can have a try?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up the SQL Azure firewall to all addresses to do a test.  Maybe when you VPN in, you are leaving through a proxy and so your actualy IP address to Azure is different.  You can set up something like:

IP range start: 0.0.0.0

IP range end: 255.255.255.255

If that works, then maybe you can do something with masking your VPN address like:

10.10.0.0 - 10.10.255.255

Comment: thanks for your answer, But it dose not explain why I can connect to the server by using same VPN through my office desktop?

Answer (score 0):

> > By not having VPN, I can connect to Azure easily. However, once I connect to the VPN, I got error when I try to connect to Azure.

Some VPNs support co-existence with normal internet connections while others don’t. I am not sure if AWS VPN supports that or not. If not, when you connect to the VPN, you lose your internet connection and thus cannot connect to SQL Azure.

> > On the other hand, I can use VPN and connect to Azure SUCCESSFULLY from my office desktop.

If the issue is related to firewall setting, you can try to change the setting programmatically, please refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/29/10043869.aspx for a sample.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but neither fits in my case. 
I can still surf internet after i had my VPN connection.
I even switched off my firewall both my laptop and Azure. 
However, no luck...